# Yahoo dkim=permerror (bad sig), gmail dkim=fail

Tags: email, postfix, dkim, spam-marked

We are using postfix(with opendkim) to send registration information from our site.

When the information sent to gmail it goes to inbox but it shows `dkim=fail`  and in Yahoo it always goes to spam with `dkim=permerror (bad sig)`

I have checked the validation of our dkim here dmarcian.com/dkim-validator/ and it says "*Congratulations! Your DKIM record is valid*."

I tried to check similar issues here but couldn't find the solution.

Thank you

Here is the header from yahoo

> X-Apparently-To: user@yahoo.com; Tue, 31 Jul 2018 11:55:46 +0000
>   Return-Path:  X-YahooFilteredBulk: MYIP
>   Received-SPF: pass (domain of mydomain.com designates MYIP as
>   permitted sender)
>
> X-YMailISG: hmw6Z7sWLDsWpJx5TJxdmlmEzfFgDeRZCgtiqTz41tl8bXJB 
>   40QDsCEPRmO_ywQTQDe4dSWQHTIisDXu...  3LWghA--
>
> X-Originating-IP: [MYIP] Authentication-Results:
>   mta4150.mail.ne1.yahoo.com  from=mydoamin.com; domainkeys=neutral (no
>   sig);  from=mydoamin.com; dkim=permerror (bad sig)
>
> Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO mydoamin.com) (MYIP)   by
>   mta4150.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTP; Tue, 31 Jul 2018 11:55:45 +0000
>   Received: by mydoamin.com (Postfix, from userid 48)   id 5DE293032FF7;
>   Tue, 31 Jul 2018 12:55:47 +0100 (BST)
>
> DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mydoamin.com 5DE293032FF7
>   DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;  d=mydoamin.com;
>   s=default; t=1533038147;
>     bh=UozQWFCbuqNeOlsvRu6cMDu9P58Wxu0Wd+RDiMn8kl0=;
>     h=To:Subject:From:Date:From;
>     b=uOjLVGUm3kCdPkzxmInk1E1mEhP88G4fWJJWvRpdHfESPGfA3GmfdEss13tmTiA5N
>   r3GHcrN6YUjUULmYhzFxACmwzPIedwEscoMmvlXpwcF8AnJcqx1qK0NuiyPxGe+ycc
>   9RkcpNPKGYoMyGmZEhjw73SKWKm+RDZMvdvPqMG4=
>
> To: user@yahoo.com Subject: Account details for aa at mydoamin.com
>   (pending admin approval) X-PHP-Originating-Script: 48:system.mail.inc
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
>   format=flowed; delsp=yes Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit X-Mailer:
>   Drupal Sender: noreply@mydoamin.com From: noreply@mydoamin.com
>   Message-Id: <20180731115547.5DE293032FF7@mydoamin.com> Date: Tue, 31
>   Jul 2018 12:55:47 +0100 (BST) Content-Length: 300

Comment: The record can be valid while the server-side setup is wrong. Make sure you're using the right signing key.

Comment: ceejayoz, thank you for your answer. I exactly followed the step from this https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-domainkeys-with-postfix-on-centos-7/. Is there any particular thing i should check?

Comment: @ceejayoz is there any way that i can check/validate the server-side setup?

Comment: @losubuntu you can try sending mail to [port25.com](https://www.port25.com/authentication-checker/) or [mail-tester.com](http://mail-tester.com/) checkers which which will check and report problems